# Python3 - How can I print a portion of a dict value?

Tags: python-3.x, python-3.6

I'm trying write a python3 script that will run a boto3 command. It calls aws sqs and returns the attribute ApproxmiteNumberOfMessages from the specified queue url. A dict is being returned as the response -

> print(response)
>
> {'Attributes': {'ApproximateNumberOfMessages': '21'}, 'ResponseMetadata': {'RequestId': '5468a1d5-d1bd-526f-a4a2-f20dbd324f5', 'HTTPStatusCode': 200, 'HTTPHeaders': {'server': 'Server', 'date': 'Mon, 30 Jul 2018 19:43:41 GMT', 'content-type': 'text/xml', 'content-length': '358', 'connection': 'keep-alive', 'x-amzn-requestid': '5448a1d4-d1bd-524f-a4a3-f20dbd1016f5'}, 'RetryAttempts': 0}}

The key I need to print is 'Attributes', but I only want the numerical value. 21 in this case.

If I print the dict plus the key I get -

> print (response['Attributes'])
>
> {'ApproximateNumberOfMessages': '21'}

How can I remove everything except the 21?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print (response['Attributes']['ApproximateNumberOfMessages'])
```

A dictionary is an array that you can address with a string

Answer (score 0):

You can just access the key as you are doing with 'Attributes', so:

```
print (response['Attributes']['ApproximateNumberOfMessages'])
```